# How to refer to a custom folder within the dictionary folder in alfresco bootstrap-context.xml?

Tags: spring, alfresco, bootstrapping

I have to upload a file to a custom folder via bootstrap. This custom folder already exist in the system in the following path.

"/app:company_home/app:dictionary/cm:abc_folder"

I am trying to upload a file to the abc_folder via bootstrap and the bean in custom-bootstrap-context.xml looks like following.

```
<bean id="custombootstrapSpaces" parent="spacesStoreImporter" scope="singleton">
  <property name="useExistingStore">
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property name="bootstrapViews">
    <list>
      <props>
        <prop key="path">/${spaces.company_home.childname}/${spaces.dictionary.childname}/cm:abc_folder</prop>
        <prop key="location">alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/bootstrap/myScript/abc.xml</prop>
      </props>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This path throws model exception. What would be the correct way to refer to an existing custom folder within the dictionary space?

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: @Gagravarr org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException I figured this is because "useExistingStore" is set to true. Is there a way to handle this other than changing it back to false?

Comment: "useExistingStore does NOT mean it will check the content structure, i.e. if you add a bootstrap for a new folder, it won't check the existence of the folder. It only checks for existance of workspace://SpacesStore and if that is not available or useExistingStore is set to true, the bootstrap will be executed. In the latter case, this means it will always be executed, leading to the conflict you have witnessed." - https://community.alfresco.com/thread/200685-how-to-properly-bootstrap-folder-in-company-home

Comment: This is working example: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk-samples/tree/alfresco-51/all-in-one/bootstrap-content-repo
Have you tried to use "Import Strategy" http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-import-strategy.html

Comment: @imagine github link was a great help. I did not have to use the import strategy.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk-samples/tree/alfresco-51/all-in-one/bootstrap-content-repo) is a source code of "Alfresco Tutorials (Bootstrap content)" that helped solve the problem.